# How to set database schema for namespace in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, schema, mapping

I have a database with multiple schemas: Security, Trade, etc.
Each shema has multiple tables. Ie. Security schema has: Users, Roles etc..

Now, can I setup nhibernate so that the schema i bound to namespace.
Ie. I have a security namespace in my project with the User and Role POCOs in it.
So I wont to set bind database schema to namespace.
I know i can add Schema in maping file for each class, but if I have ie. 1000 class i must specify schema for each clas.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do what you want programatically right before you create your sessionfactory like this:

```
var cfg = new Configuration().Configure();
foreach (var pc in cfg.ClassMappings)
{//just an example
     pc.Table.Schema = pc.MappedClass.Assembly.GetName().FullName.Substring(0, 3);
}
var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

note that normally you only build your session factory once so the performance impact (if any) happens only once.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate won't do it magically. If you want to avoid changing mapping files manually, use a code-based solution like ConfORM or FluentNHibernate instead.